# $.getJSON not parsing object in callback

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I have a simple getJson request:

```
$.getJSON('JsonTest', function(o) {
alert(o.Test);
});
```

It works, but in Firebug the "o" never gets turned into an object, but stays a string:

```
{"Test":"Hello"}
```

If I do an

```
eval('(' + o + ')')
```

It gets evaluated fine, the only thing I can think of is that there's some sort of cross site scripting problem, but I'm running everything on my development machine, the JsonTest is off of localhost:port/Controller/JsonTest

Any ideas as to what could be wrong? How do I check to see whether or not it is a cross site issue? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that your JsonTest service is "double escaping" the json that gets sent back? As in:

`"{\"Test\":\"Hello\"}"`

Since you have firebug, can you take a look at the response and paste the raw text that it shows?

If your service method returns a string, and you are doing your own serialization, then this is definitely the case.  I ran in to this recently.  Anyway, with the "double quoted" (or double wrapped, double escaped, whatever you want to call it) json coming back, $.getJSON() only eval()'s it once, turning `"{\"Test\":\"Hello\"}"` into `{"Test":"Hello"}`, which does indeed still require an additional eval().

Also, don't use eval().  Use `JSON.parse()`.  You can include json2.js from http://json.org/, and JSON.parse() will either use the browser's native json parsing abilities, or fall back on json2.js if the browser doesn't do it natively.

Comment: You're right! Oh my God all afternoon on this! I was doing a Public JsonResult() ... return Json(TestJson) ... and in between was serializing by hand (long story), so when I called Json it would serialize again. Wow, all afternoon on this. This explains why my other JsonResults were working fine. Wow, thanks again.

Comment: You're lucky you only spent *1* afternoon on it, haha.  I think it took me 2 ;-)